# 301 Redirect - Can I maintain links to pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I will set the scene

I have a lot of backlinks to pages all over my site

Do I need a 301 rule for each link or can I have one for the whole site eg

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^website.uk.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

want to maintain:
www.website.uk.com/page.html to www.website.com/page.html

not redirect:
www.website.uk.com/page.html to www.website.com

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me (I have a similar rule on my web-site, below adapted to your domains):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.uk.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.uk.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried this and got a 500 error - when I had just one rewrite condition it worked but - every url was redirected to the new one

Comment: 500 errors means that there was an error in your program. Was it caused by issues with URLs? Were urls redirected properly?

Comment: I fixed the 500 error - it was a space in [NC, OR] should be [NC,OR] - still the redirect from www.website.uk.com/webpage.html goes to www.website.com so thats not correct - I will check my other redirects?

Comment: Sorry for the typo (fixed). That is a good point. Probably there are other redirects. This one works perfectly for me, and redirects to www.site.com/page not just to www.site.com

Answer (score 0):

You can have one rule for the whole site.

Comment: I have tried the rule above but it redirects www.website.uk.com/page.html to www.website.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you try two seperate rules with an `OR` ?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^website.uk.com [nc, OR]
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.website.uk.com [nc]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```